# Switch between Mongo production and test database - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the following model:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Document
public class Customer {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;


    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

And the following repository:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

The `development` database contains the `customers` collections, which contains the real data - the information regarding real customers. 
As a big fan of `TDD`, I created the following Unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CustomerTest.class})
public class CustomerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
           // I want to delete the test database, not the production one
           repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateCustomer() {

       // save a couple of customers
       repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
       repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

       // fetch all customers
       System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
           System.out.println(customer);
       }
       System.out.println();

       // fetch an individual customer
       System.out.println("Customer found with     findByFirstName('Alice'):");
       System.out.println("--------------------------------");
       System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

       System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
       System.out.println("--------------------------------");
       for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
           System.out.println(customer);
       }
    }       
}
```

Of course I have a `SpringMongoConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(this.host + ":" + this.port), database);
    }

    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory()),
                new MongoMappingContext());
        converter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("\\+");

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), converter);

        return mongoTemplate;

    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return this.database;
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient(this.host, this.port);
    }
}
```

How can I switch between `production` and `test` databases while executing unit tests?

Comment: A note: what has your data model to do with the question, other that both are related to MongoDB somehow? Other than that, you can use environment variables for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I prefer to use an embedded database for testing. You can use [FakeMongo](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo)

```
package com.backend.configuration;

import com.github.fakemongo.Fongo;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.backend.repository")
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  private static final String DB_NAME = "test";

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return DB_NAME;
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public Mongo mongo() {
    return new Fongo(getDatabaseName()).getMongo();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return "com.backend.domain";
  }
}
```

In test class :

```
package com.backend.repository;

import com.backend.configuration.MongoConfiguration;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MongoConfiguration.class)
public class CustomerRepositoryTest {

}
```

For the other profiles like development and production, you can use spring boot profile (see [doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)) or you can use maven profile :
in `application.properties` add this property `spring.data.mongodb.host=@mongo.host@` then define it in `pom.xml`accroding to used profile :

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <mongo.host>localhost</mongo.host>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <mongo.host>mongo</mongo.host>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 4):

The most easy way to do it is just override desired properties in your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
    "spring.data.mongodb.database=test_db"
})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CustomerTest.class})
public class CustomerTest {
```

In case you need  to redefine bean - for instance use in-memory fongo  implementation you can create `CustomTestConfig` and add it to your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)  
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CustomTestConfig.class})
public class CustomerTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch online database or test database, use test database when unit test. you can use `@Conditional` annotation on your datasource config.
Here is the way:

1. Add class to impl `Conditional`. One of the online condition, the other of the test condition.You can just impl this two conditional class by read `yml` config
2. Add those condition to your data source config:

`@Conditional(Online.class)
    @Component
    class OnlineDatasrouceConfig{
    }`

`@Conditional(OnTest.class)
    @Component
    class TestDatasrouceConfig{
    }`

Then, spring will create the bean only when conditional is true.

Here is the condition document:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-condition-annotations

And, there is some other way to switch test database when you are running unit test.
Add `@ActiveProfile("test")` to your test class. spring will use `test.yml` to init this test class. And, you just need to put your test database config in `test.yml`(I AM USE THIS WAY)