# Java + Docker: Different datasource url

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project which I want to run in a docker environment. The project is split up in different modules each having it's own Dockerfile so I'm using docker compose to combine these. I have one service for the db:

```
db:
      image: postgres:9.5
      ports:
       - 5432:5432
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
        POSTGRES_DB: db1
```

The module which work with the db has the datasource set: `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/db1`

The problem is that I have colleagues who do not want to run it in docker for performance reasons (Windows + Mac user). They rely on `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1`. Can I use different datasources depending on the environment the module is running?

Comment: see my answer to  this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580088/switch-between-mongo-production-and-test-database-java-spring-boot/40607152#40607152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You will find everything you want to know here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html